# Graphql query array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, graphql, relay

I'm trying to fetch an array of coordinates with graphql. I'm using relay, mongoose, and graffiti-mongoose to generate graphql types from these mongoose models:

```
// Geometry
const GeometrySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
type:         { type: String }, 
coordinates:  [ Number ]
}, { _id: false } );

// Country 
const CountrySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
code:           String,
name:           String,
dictionary:     [ { _id: false, value: String } ],
language:       [ { _id: false, code: String, name: String } ],
loc:            { type: { type: String }, geometries: [ GeometrySchema ] },
creationDate:   Date,
modifiedDate:   Date
});

const Country = mongoose.model('Country', CountrySchema);
```

Here's the generated graphql (graphql/utilities):

```
type Country implements Node {
  code: String
  name: String
  dictionary: [CountryDictionary]
  language: [CountryLanguage]
  loc: [CountryLoc]
  creationDate: Date
  modifiedDate: Date
  _id: ID
  id: ID!
}

type CountryConnection {
  pageInfo: PageInfo!
  edges: [CountryEdge]
  count: Float
}

type CountryDictionary {
  _id: Generic
  value: String
}

input CountryDictionaryInput {
  _id: Generic
  value: String
}

type CountryEdge {
  node: Country
  cursor: String!
}

type CountryLanguage {
  _id: Generic
  code: String
  name: String
}

input CountryLanguageInput {
  _id: Generic
  code: String
  name: String
}

type CountryLoc {
  type: String
  coordinates: [Float]
}

input CountryLocInput {
  type: String
  coordinates: [Float]
}
```

Using graphiql I can get the country's name with this:

```
{
  country(id:"57b48b73f6d183802aa06fe8"){
    name

  } 
}
```

How can I retrieve the loc info?

Comment: Did you try out `{
  country(id:"57b48b73f6d183802aa06fe8"){
    name
    loc {
      coordinates
    }
  } 
}`
?

Comment: Yes I try, I get this response:
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "Expected Iterable, but did not find one for field Country.loc."
}

Comment: That means, the problem has to do with server-side implementation. Check if you return an array of coordinates properly on the server-side.

Answer (score 0):

According to your schema, the query would looks like this

```
{
  country(id:"57b48b73f6d183802aa06fe8") {
    name
    loc {
      type
      coordinates
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your response. With that query I got this result:
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "error": "Bad Request",
  "message": "Expected Iterable, but did not find one for field Country.loc."
}

Comment: Your mongoose `CountrySchema` has `loc` property defined as a single object, instead of array.
And your Type schema has loc field defined as list `[CountryLoc]`.
Your model simply doesn't return an array

Comment: Yes, you are right. The mongoose model it´s ok but the utility graffiti-mongoose used to generate the graphql types has limitations with subdocuments. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a possible bug in the schema creation, I could make it work with this model (see example folder): https://github.com/tothandras/graffiti-mongoose/tree/bug/ric_castro_rada

Comment: Thank you András. I will give a try with that model.